# How to add audio to .click function

Tags: html5-audio

How is it possible to add audio to this script, so when I "click" the audio will play. 
Is there a simple code I can add to this one to make that work or is there a different way?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#fire').click(function(){
$('#missile').animate({top:-400},1000, function() {
$('#missile').css({top: '600', bottom: '-100px'});
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

Problem solved ty

Answer (score -2):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

Onclick, create an html element like

```
<object height="50" width="100" data="horse.mp3"></object>
```

And append it to $("body")